# D3.JS Vertical line separating year

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello i'm having some difficulties with D3.JS , I need to insert a vertical dotted line separating two columns. The x axis is a date, and I'm trying to insert the line when a new year starts.

Fiddle link with full Javascript:http://jsfiddle.net/GAv9y/

My current code for printing the graph is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="Panel-reports-graph" class="PanelTpl-reports grid_12 rounded-corners">
<h1 class="rounded-corners">Changes Historical Graphic</h1>
<div class="narrow_2">
<div id="Widget75-Loading" class="Loading-div" align="center" style="display: none;">
<div id="Widget75" class="Widget-Tpl-graph" align="center">
<style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="dropdown-container">
<ul id="75" class="graph-dropdown" rel="0">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
initDropdown();
</script>
<div id="graph-27">
<svg width="900" height="350">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
var barGroup = graph.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "bars")
                        .selectAll(".bar-group")
                        .data(barData)
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "bar-group")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "translate(" + x0(d.date) + ",0)";
                        });

                if (options.other.stackedbar == "true") {

                    var bar = barGroup.selectAll("rect")
                            .data(function(d) {
                                return d.values;
                            })
                            .enter().append("rect")
                            .attr("width", x0.rangeBand())
                            .attr("x", function(d) {
                                return x1(d.date);;

                            })
                            .attr("y", function(d) {
                                return y(d.aggr);
                            })
                            .attr("height", function(d) {
                                return height - y(d.value);
                            })
                            .style("fill", function(d) {
                                return color(d.serie);
                            });
                       }
```

barData

```
var data = [],
lineData = [],
barData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.abscisa.length; i++) {

                    var serieName,
                            length = 0;

                    var row = {
                        date: isNaN(Date.parse(json.abscisa[i])) ? json.abscisa[i] : d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(json.abscisa[i])
                    };

                    var barRow = {
                        date: isNaN(Date.parse(json.abscisa)) ? json.abscisa[i] : d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(json.abscisa[i])
                    };

                    var lineRow = {
                        date: isNaN(Date.parse(json.abscisa)) ? json.abscisa[i] : d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(json.abscisa[i])
                    };

                    for (var j = 0; j < json.series.length; j++) {

                        serieName = json.series[j];

                        row[serieName] = json[serieName].data[i];

                        switch (json[serieName].metadata.align) {

                            case 'V':

                                barRow[serieName] = json[serieName].data[i];

                                break;

                            default:

                                lineRow[serieName] = json[serieName].data[i];

                                break;
                        }

                    }

                    data.push(row);

                    length = 0;

                    for (key in lineRow)
                        length++;
                    if (length > 1)
                        lineData.push(lineRow);

                    length = 0;

                    for (key in barRow)
                        length++;
                    if (length > 1)
                        barData.push(barRow);

                }
```

### UPDATE: Thank you @Lars Kotthoff, it's working almost perfect at the moment! I understand very little of Js so it took me a while to make it work

For line graphics it works perfectly, but for bar graphs the line gets displaced to the left. I was told there should be an option to center it if anybody knows what it is??

Code block below:

```
    var time = d3.time.format("%Y %m %d"),
                        xscale = d3.time.scale()
                        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                            return d.date;
                        }))
                        .range([0, width]),
                        yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                            return d[1];
                        }))
                        .range([height, 0]);

                var startEnd = xscale.domain().map(function(d) {
                    return d.getFullYear();
                }),
                        years = d3.range(startEnd[0] + 1, startEnd[1] + 1);

                graph.selectAll(".divide").data(years)
                        .enter().append("line")
                        .attr("class", "divide")
                        .attr("opacity","1")
                        .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
                        .attr("y1", yscale.range()[0])
                        .attr("y2", yscale.range()[1])
                        .attr("x1", function(d) {
                            return xscale(new Date(d, 0));
                        })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) {
                            return xscale(new Date(d, 0));
                        });
```

Comment: Please also paste your html. (Coding html by our own with all classes will be time consuming)

Comment: Updated the code, sorry for the lack of information and thank you for your time. Hope the block of HTML is enough.

Comment: What is your `barData` ?

Comment: can u add the fiddle?

Comment: I've posted the barData code, I'm not quite sure how this works, my understanding of Javascript is limited. But this should retrieve the X axis date values.

Comment: You pasted the generated html to the fiddle? And there are PHP in your js. :/

Comment: Yes I'm sorry but this code is quite weird, it spawns over several different files so this was the best way i could give an example of the code, and the data is retrieved from an external database. I have very little experience with posting questions in here sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach that I would take.

- Get the earliest and the latest date from your scale.
- Get the year for each of those.
- Generate a range from the year after the earliest (because that's where your first divider will be) to the last.
- Pass this range to `.data()` and bind to lines.

In code, this would look like this, assuming that `xscale` is your time scale and `yscale` the scale for your y axis.

```
var startEnd = xscale.domain().map(function(d) { return d.getFullYear(); }),
  years = d3.range(startEnd[0]+1, startEnd[1]+1);

svg.selectAll(".divide").data(years)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "divide")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "1,1")
  .attr("y1", yscale.range()[0])
  .attr("y2", yscale.range()[1])
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return xscale(new Date(d, 0)); })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return xscale(new Date(d, 0)); });
```

The `stroke-dasharray` property is set to make it appear as a dotted line. Complete example [here](https://vida.io/documents/iv7e43m9bd3A9NBYP).

Comment: Hi, thannk you very much the example is nearly perfect for me. But i'm having serious problems adapting it to my case. I can get the years from my data, but i can¡t manage to print it to my graph.
I've uploaded my entire code to http://jsfiddle.net/GAv9y/3/. I have 3 types of graphics Bar , lines and both.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me. It looks like it should work though. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well it started printing now so its an improvement! I have no idea why it wasnt printing. Well now i just need to understand how choose the correct value for X. I dont really need to insert a new tick for the year separator, i can use the first entry of the year that appears.
This Jsfiddle should show now http://jsfiddle.net/GAv9y/8/, the code changes you provided are at:
HTML: line 280
Javascript code: lines 316,458
thank you so much for your trouble.

Comment: Your new jsfiddle doesn't work for me either, but it looks like you're not using the code I've posted -- have a look at how the x position for the separating lines are computed.